# NVD3 line chart display X axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I would like to make a line chart with nvd3(which is a collection of re-usable charts made with d3.js), which has y and x axis represented by a line.

Here is the line chart example from the official nvd3 site:

http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html

I would like something like this, where the X axis line displayed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmzLA.png

Has nvd3 any options for that? Is it even possible? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it's controlled by this CSS rule (nv.d3.css line 225):

```
.nvd3 .nv-axis.nv-x path.domain {
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}
```

Overriding that with your own CSS should show the line (at least, changing the value to 1 in the developer tools worked for me).

Comment: It works! Thank you! Howewer, when i have two charts in the same page, the second one only shows the x axis when i add this line to the code:
`chart.legend.margin({top: 10, right:130, left:0, bottom: 5});`
I have no idea why. It's strange.

Answer (score 2):

```
.nvd3 .nv-axis.nv-x path.domain, .nvd3 .nv-axis.nv-y path.domain {
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```